# Trying to get the right arrow head on my Feyman diagram

Tags: pdftex, luatex, feynman, tikz-feynman

So this is the code that genreates the image below. I am trying to get the pointed arrows on the fermions but I have no idea why is not working wit particle. Any help will be appreciated.

```
\feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=i2 to d] {
a -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] i2 [dot] -- [anti charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] { b  --  c1 [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)], b -- c2 [particle=\
(\nu_\mu\)] }, i2 --[double,with arrow=0.5,edge label=$\mathcal{R}$] { d 
--[charged scalar,edge label=$\pi^0$]  d1 , d -- [fermion,edge 
label=$N$]d2} ,
};
\caption{\label{fig:irs} RES}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many fermion lines in your diagram and I couldn't understand what you mean by "is not working wit particle". However, I put arrows on the two fermion lines that did not have them before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=i2 to d] {
a -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] i2 [dot] -- [anti charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] { b  --[fermion]  c1 [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)], b --[anti fermion] c2 [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] }, i2 --[double,with arrow=0.5,edge label=$\mathcal{R}$] { d 
--[charged scalar,edge label=$\pi^0$]  d1 , d -- [fermion,edge label=$N$]d2} 
};
\end{document}
```

[image]